# PHP: Two basic questions about URL

Tags: php

**Question 1**

www.example.com/**?do=blah**

How do you get it to work without index.php? Any examples?

**Question 2**

www.example.com/news.php?blah

This link doesn't show the same result as news.php, but shouldn't we be using news.php&blah=value for example? What does the string after ? stand for? Shortened version of GET variables or an entirely different thing?

Comment: For Q1, as long as your web server is configured to serve `index.php` as the directory index, it will work automatically in PHP without `index.php`.

Comment: For Q2 we would need to see the code in `news.php` and possibly also .htaccess if there is one to be able to say for certain what's being done.

Comment: You should post these as separate questions.

Comment: @Michael; I can't provide the code, but the live example is here. (http://www.solomid.net/news.php?lolnews) @kaoD; I thought these questions were similar, so I asked it together.

Comment: @AnılÜnal we can't say for sure without seeing the code. I would guess there is a rewrite taking place at the server level which is mapping `?blah` to a full GET parameter like `?article=blah`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question 1**

As long as `index.php` is your default and you have it present in your root folder then you only need to have `www.domain.com/?querystring=value`

**Question 2**

`?` is the beginning of a querystring parameter.  It should be used for the first one.

`&` is for every querystring parameter after that.

`index.php?querystring1=value&querystring2=value&querystring3=value` and so on.

Comment: Actually, "query string" refers to everything after `?` and before `#`.

Comment: Additionally for Question 2, the `blah` by itself could be a route that would be processed by the code in your php file.

Comment: Question 1: So it doesn't require any special coding in PHP-side? Question 2: Yes, but querystring1 doesn't have any values appointed. (here: http://www.solomid.net/news.php?lolnews) Does it automatically appoints "true" for example?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, I was referring to `querystring` as individual querystring values.

Comment: There is no such thing as "individual querystring values". There is **one** entire query string, ampersands and all.

Comment: @AnılÜnal, usually this is a "route" or command that is read and processed by the php file.  It would require special `.htaccess` or other server directives to be meaningful to the php file.  Without the directives the command will result in a 404 file not found error.

Comment: @seanbreeden; So, there's a .htaccess file is lying around? If so, that's okay. I thought it was just a PHP feature.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams - Yes, it may be "one querystring" but it is often referred to as "individual querystring values" when talking about the values that make up the querystring.

Comment: @seanbreeden; I've read the other comments too, so we definitely need a .htaccess file for the second question. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Maybe I should have said "individual querystring parameters"?   What is the exact terminology I should use to refer to the individual values that make up the querystring?

Answer (score 1):

You can configure a URL rewrite using `.htaccess` for both of 'em.

```
RewriteEngine On
#for question 1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
#another example for question 2
RewriteRule ^news.php\?(.*)$ news.php?blah=$1 [L]
```

The first example will capture everything and redirect the user to the `index.php` file. So if the user tries to access `domain.tld/abc` they'll actually be accessing `domain.tld/index.php/abc`

As for the second example, it will grab the everything that is part of the query string (a better Regex might be needed). Basically, it'll turn `news.php?value` to `news.php?blah=value`

Comment: It solved my second question, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't entirely understand your second question, but the answer to your first question is that you need to specify a different default directory index on your webserver. Assuming you are running Apache, find this line in the httpd.conf file:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php ...etc
```

and change it to:

```
DirectoryIndex your_preferred_default_page.php
```

For your second question, the question mark is not shorthand, it marks the beginning of a query string... it's used as a cue to treat futher strings as GET keys and values.